# Replace last text ocurrence in a file with sed

Tags: sed, replace

I'm tying to replace the last occurrence of a word in a file.

```
hello
bye
bye
bye
hello
```

I am able to replace it by indicating the line number.

```
sed -i '4 s/bye/adieu' file
```

Also, if the occurrence is in the last line.

```
sed -i '$ s/hello/salut' file
```

But, how can I find and replace the last `bye` without indicating the line number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KSH: sed command to search and replace last occurrence of a string in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249244/ksh-sed-command-to-search-and-replace-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. As mentioned in the post of the provided link, using tail -2 file | sed 's/bye/adieu/g'  it works, but it is necessary to know the position of the last occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit gross and probably not recommended for large files, but it should work:

```sh
sed -zE '$ s/(.*)bye/\1adieu/' file
```

where `-z` makes Sed consider the whole file as a single line with `\n` interspersed, and `-E` is to use `()` instead of `\(\)`.

If there's a chance that a line contains `bye` but is not just `bye`, as in `goodbye`/`good bye`/whatever, than you can go with

```sh
sed -zE '$ s/(.*)(^|\n)bye($|\n)/\1adieu/' file
```

Comment: For my current needs, it works perfectly. Thanks Enlico.

Comment: @Jota, in this case, why not upvoting me too?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using `tac | gnu-sed | sed`:

```sh
tac file | sed '0,/^bye$/ s//adieu/' | tac

hello
bye
bye
adieu
hello
```

**Details:**

- `tac` prints file in reverse
- `0,/^bye$/` matches a line from beginning to first occurrence of `bye` line
- `s//adieu/` substitutes that line with `adieu`
- `tac` prints file in reverse again to get original order

---

**Alternatively** this `awk` solution would work in any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {if ($0 == "bye") last = FNR; next}
FNR == last {$0 = "adieu"} 1' file file

hello
bye
bye
adieu
hello
```

Comment: I had already been using tac, but it only displays the output, it does not edit the file. Thanks anubhava.

Comment: For saving changes use: `tac file | sed '0,/^bye$/ s//adieu/' | tac > _tmp && mv _tmp file`